# How to do form validation in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

am trying to do angular form validation while doing am facing below problems getting difficulty to clear

1) when i click submit without filling inputs getting validation messages which is not in red color and am not getting validation message itself for phone number field

2)when i type something like in name text box i typed my name and remove all the characters then text box gets red but no validation message like name is required

3) In email filed while started to type itself its showing message please enter valid mail id

4) in phone number field if i enter character its giving right validation message but if i keep on pressing more than 10 characters  its giving please enter 10 digit i need to avoid this

This is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cL2q3z6v/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <div class="page-header"></div>
    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- FORM ============================================================== -->
    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)"  novalidate="" id="userForm">

     <!-- NAME -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid &amp;&amp; !userForm.name.$pristine }">
      <label>Name*</label> 
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required="" />
        <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">Name is required.</p>
      </div>

      <!-- USERNAME -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid &amp;&amp; !userForm.username.$pristine }">
      <label>Username</label> 
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8" required="" />
        <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.required && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">Username is required.</p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
      </div>




      <!-- EMAIL -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid &amp;&amp; !userForm.email.$pristine }">
      <label>Email</label> 
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required="" />
        <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
      </div>



      <!-- PHONE -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.phone.$invalid &amp;&amp; !userForm.phone.$pristine }">
      <label>Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" ng-model="user.phone" ng-pattern="phoneNumbr" ng-maxlength="10" placeholder="+91-636-78658" />
        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.required  && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">Phone number is Required</p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Ten digit Required</p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.pattern" class="help-block">Please enter digits like 9964289813</p>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" ng-model="user.gender" ng-required="!user.gender"/> Male</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value=
            "female" ng-model="user.gender" ng-required="!user.gender"/> Female</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value=
            "other" ng-model="user.gender" ng-required="!user.gender"/> Other</label>
          </div>
           <p ng-show="userForm.gender.$error.required  && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">Gender is Required</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <select name="country" class="form-control" required="" ng-model="user.country">
            <option value="">Select a country</option>
            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
          </select>
          <p ng-show="userForm.country.$error.required  && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">country is Required</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Browser</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="browsers" value="chrome"  ng-model="user.browser['chrome']" ng-required="!browser(user.browser)"/> Google Chrome</label>
          </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="browsers" value="firefox" ng-model="user.browser['firefox']" ng-required="!browser(user.browser)"/> Firefox</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="browsers" value="ie" ng-model="user.browser['ie']"  ng-required="!browser(user.browser)"/> IE</label>
          </div>
          <p ng-show="userForm.browsers.$error.required  && userForm.$submitted" class="help-block">Browser is Required</p>
        </div>
      </div><br />

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.phoneNumbr = /^\+?\d{2}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{5}$/;
     $scope.browser = function (object) {
      return Object.keys(object).some(function (key) {
        return object[key];
      });
    }
       $scope.user = {};

    $scope.user.browser = {};

       // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred   
       $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) { 
         alert('our form is amazing');
        }

       };

      });
```

Comment: What do you exactly want? Can you be a bit more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the validation errors below the form inputs, my starting choice would be creating a field containing the error message and a ng-if attribute. It could be as simple as adding ng-if="angular.isUndefined(inputModelVariableName)" to your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

you have some `syntax errors` with your code, and also the angular errors.

Also, please `indent and format the code`, so that it is easy for you to understand.

**Here is the solved requirement, with formatted code and all the fields are validated, check the snippet or fiddle.**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.phoneNumbr = /^\+?\d{2}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{5}$/;
      $scope.browser = function (object) {
        return Object.keys(object).some(function (key) {
          return object[key];
        });
      }
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.browser = {};
    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred   
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
      
    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if (isValid) { 
      alert('our form is amazing');
    }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <div class="page-header"></div>
    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- FORM ============================================================== -->
    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)"
    novalidate="" id="userForm">
      <!-- NAME -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class=
      "{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid &amp;&amp; !userForm.name.$pristine }">
      <label>Name*</label> <input type="text" name="name" class=
      "form-control" ng-model="user.name" required="" />
        <p ng-show="(userForm.name.$invalid && userForm.$submitted) || (userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine)" class="help-block">
          You name is required.
        </p>
      </div><!-- USERNAME -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class=
      "{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid &amp;&amp; !userForm.username.$pristine }">
      <label>Username</label> <input type="text" name="username"
      class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength=
      "3" ng-maxlength="8" required="" />
        <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.required && userForm.$submitted || (userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine)" class=
        "help-block">
          Username is required.
        </p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class=
        "help-block">
          Username is too short.
        </p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class=
        "help-block">
          Username is too long.
        </p>
      </div><!-- EMAIL -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class=
      "{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid &amp;&amp; !userForm.email.$pristine }">
      <label>Email</label> <input type="email" name="email"
        class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required="" />
        <p ng-show="(userForm.email.$invalid && userForm.$submitted) || (userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine)" class="help-block">
          Enter a valid email.
        </p>
      </div><!-- PHONE -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class=
      "{ 'has-error' : userForm.phone.$invalid &amp;&amp; !userForm.phone.$pristine }">
      <label>Phone Number</label> <input type="text" name="phone"
      class="form-control" ng-model="user.phone" ng-pattern=
      "phoneNumbr" ng-maxlength="10" placeholder="+91-636-78658" />
        <p ng-show="(userForm.phone.$error.required  && userForm.$submitted) || (userForm.phone.$invalid && !userForm.phone.$pristine)" class=
        "help-block">
          Phone number is Required
        </p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.maxlength" class=
        "help-block">
          Ten digit Required
        </p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.pattern" class=
        "help-block">
          Please enter digits like 9964289813
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value=
            "male" ng-model="user.gender" ng-required="!user.gender"/> Male</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value=
            "female" ng-model="user.gender" ng-required="!user.gender"/> Female</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value=
            "other" ng-model="user.gender" ng-required="!user.gender"/> Other</label>
          </div>
           <p ng-show="(userForm.gender.$error.required  && userForm.$submitted) || (userForm.gender.$invalid && !userForm.gender.$pristine)" class=
        "help-block">
          Gender is Required
        </p>
        </div>
      </div><br />
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <select name="country" class="form-control" required=""
          ng-model="user.country">
            <option value="">
              Select a country
            </option>
            <option value="AU">
              Australia
            </option>
            <option value="CA">
              Canada
            </option>
            <option value="FR">
              France
            </option>
          </select>
          <p ng-show="(userForm.country.$error.required  && userForm.$submitted)  || (userForm.country.$invalid && !userForm.country.$pristine)" class=
          "help-block">
            country is Required
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-5 control-label">Browser</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="browsers" value=
            "chrome"  ng-model="user.browser['chrome']"
    ng-required="!browser(user.browser)"
/> Google Chrome</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="browsers" value=
            "firefox" ng-model="user.browser['firefox']"
    ng-required="!browser(user.browser)"/> Firefox</label>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="browsers" value=
            "ie" ng-model="user.browser['ie']"
    ng-required="!browser(user.browser)"/> IE</label>
          </div>
          <p ng-show="(userForm.browsers.$error.required  && userForm.$submitted)  || (userForm.browsers.$invalid && !userForm.browsers.$pristine)" class=
          "help-block">
            Browser is Required
          </p>
        </div>
      </div><br />
    
  <button type="submit" class=
  "btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Please run this snippet**

[Here is a fiddle for it.](https://jsfiddle.net/mkLw6331/5/)

Comment: ya @Sravan i want to validate rest of the fields checkbox, radio button and dropdown can you show me how to do that

Comment: check the updated answer now, all the fields are validated

Comment: see there before typing or before submit am getting validation messages

Comment: all the validation message is showing except phone before doing anything,

Comment: you can even check the snippet in the answer.

Comment: username required message should display when i submit without enter data and when i remove all characters. now what happening is when i remove all characters textbox gets red but no message

Comment: okay, I didn't knw that requirement,  chck this lik  now https://jsfiddle.net/mkLw6331/6/

Comment: @jancypradeep, did you check now?

Comment: @ya But not everything perfect

Comment: help me am not getting

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine after adding `jQuery`. It wasn't there in your fiddle.

Here's a link: http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/woeggw

Comment: can you show me how validate rest of the fields like drop down , checkbox and radio button on submit

Comment: After working for a while on it, I have made it to work. Here's the updated link:http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/woeggw?editors=1010. Be free to ask anything if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Below code Works as my Expectation

```js
//defining module
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
 
//creating custom directive
myapp.directive('ngCompare', function () {
 return {
 require: 'ngModel',
 link: function (scope, currentEl, attrs, ctrl) {
 var comparefield = document.getElementsByName(attrs.ngCompare)[0]; //getting first element
 compareEl = angular.element(comparefield);
 
 //current field key up
 currentEl.on('keyup', function () {
 if (compareEl.val() != "") {
 var isMatch = currentEl.val() === compareEl.val();
 ctrl.$setValidity('compare', isMatch);
 scope.$digest();
 }
 });
 
 //Element to compare field key up
 compareEl.on('keyup', function () {
 if (currentEl.val() != "") {
 var isMatch = currentEl.val() === compareEl.val();
 ctrl.$setValidity('compare', isMatch);
 scope.$digest();
 }
 });
 }
 }
});
 
// create angular controller
myapp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
 
 $scope.countryList = [
 { CountryId: 1, Name: 'India' },
 { CountryId: 2, Name: 'USA' }
 ];
 
 $scope.cityList = [];
 
 $scope.$watch('user.country', function (newVal,oldVal) {
 
 if (newVal == 1)
 $scope.cityList = [
 { CountryId: 1, CityId: 1, Name: 'Noida' },
 { CountryId: 1, CityId: 2, Name: 'Delhi' }];
 else if (newVal == 2)
 $scope.cityList = [
 { CountryId: 2, CityId: 3, Name: 'Texas' },
 { CountryId: 2, CityId: 4, Name: 'NewYork' }];
 else
 $scope.cityList = [];
 });
 
 // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred 
 $scope.submitForm = function () {
 
 // Set the 'submitted' flag to true
 $scope.submitted = true;
 
 if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
 alert("Form is valid!");
 }
 else {
 alert("Please correct errors!");
 }
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mainController">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
 
 <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
 <div class="page-header"><h1>AngularJS Form Validation</h1></div>
 
 <!-- FORM : YOU CAN DISABLE, HTML5 VALIDATION BY USING "novalidate" ATTRIBUTE-->
 <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
 
 <!-- NAME -->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && (userForm.name.$dirty || submitted)}">
 <label>Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Your Name" ng-required="true">
 <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required && (userForm.name.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
 </div>
 
 <!-- USERNAME -->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && (userForm.username.$dirty || submitted)}">
 <label>Username</label>
 <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Your Username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8" ng-required="true">
 <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.required && (userForm.username.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">You username is required.</p>
 <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength && (userForm.username.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
 <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength && (userForm.username.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
 </div>
 
 <!-- PASSWORD -->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.password.$invalid && (userForm.password.$dirty || submitted)}">
 <label>Password</label>
 <input type="Password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Your Password" ng-required="true">
 <p ng-show="userForm.password.$error.required && (userForm.password.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Your password is required.</p>
 </div>
 
 <!-- CONFIRM PASSWORD -->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.confirmPassword.$invalid && (userForm.confirmPassword.$dirty || submitted)}">
 <label>Confirm Password</label>
 <input type="Password" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" ng-model="user.confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Your Password" ng-compare="password" ng-required="true">
 <p ng-show="userForm.confirmPassword.$error.required && (userForm.confirmPassword.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Your confirm password is required.</p>
 <p ng-show="userForm.confirmPassword.$error.compare && (userForm.confirmPassword.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Confirm password doesnot match.</p>
 </div>
 
 <!-- EMAIL -->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && (userForm.email.$dirty || submitted)}">
 <label>Email</label>
 <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Your Email Address" ng-required="true">
 <p ng-show="userForm.email.$error.required && (userForm.email.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Email is required.</p>
 <p ng-show="userForm.email.$error.email && (userForm.email.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
 </div>
 
 <!-- CONTACTNO -->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.contactno.$invalid && (userForm.contactno.$dirty || submitted) }">
 <label>ContactNo</label>
 <input type="text" name="contactno" class="form-control" ng-model="user.contactno" placeholder="Your Contact No" ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" maxlength="10">
 <p ng-show="userForm.contactno.$error.pattern && (userForm.contactno.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Enter a valid contactno.</p>
 </div>
 
 <!-- COUNTRY -->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.country.$invalid && (userForm.country.$dirty || submitted)}">
 <label>Country</label>
 <select name="country" class="form-control"
 ng-model="user.country"
 ng-options="country.CountryId as country.Name for country in countryList"
 ng-required="true">
 <option value=''>Select</option>
 </select>
 <p ng-show="userForm.country.$error.required && (userForm.country.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Select country.</p>
 </div>
 
 <!-- CITY -->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.city.$invalid && (userForm.city.$dirty || submitted)}">
 <label>City</label>
 <select name="city" class="form-control"
 ng-model="user.city"
 ng-options="city.CityId as city.Name for city in cityList"
 ng-required="true">
 <option value=''>Select</option>
 </select>
 <p ng-show="userForm.city.$error.required && (userForm.city.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Select city.</p>
 </div>
 
 <!-- TERMS & CONDITIONS -->
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.terms.$invalid && (userForm.terms.$dirty || submitted)}">
 <label>Accept Terms & Conditions</label>
 <input type="checkbox" value="" name="terms" ng-model="user.terms" ng-required="true" />
 <p ng-show="userForm.terms.$error.required && (userForm.terms.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Accept terms & conditions.</p>
 </div>
 
 <!-- ng-disabled FOR ENABLING AND DISABLING SUBMIT BUTTON -->
 <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Register</button>-->
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 <br />
</body>
```